# Wordpress Blog on Heroku server

Tags: ruby, wordpress, heroku

My ruby website is developed and hosted on heroku server(mysite.com).Now i developed a wordpress blog(using mysql) for the same site.I need to host this blog on Herku too.
Is it possible to host wordpress blog on Heroku server?possible to host my blog like 
blog.mysite.com?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible.  Use the cleardb add-on to get a MySQL database instead of using the default Heroku DB, which is postgres (it's possible to convert Wordpress to use Postgres to some degree, but I wouldn't recommend it).  Also, use a custom buildpack, because the default PHP buildpack blocks on a single request and has no support for extensions required by many common plugins.  For example you can use [my custom buildpack](https://github.com/andrewsg/heroku-buildpack-php-foundry) which is tuned specifically for Wordpress or [my buildpack's parent](https://github.com/winglian/heroku-buildpack-php) which is more general-purpose.